# PowerShell Script Error in command but works in ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am running a script in the ISE that essentially downloads a file from a public site:

```
#This PowerShell code scrapes the site and downloads the latest published file.  
Param( 
    $Url = 'https://randomwebsite.com',
    $DownloadPath = "C:\Downloads", 
    $LocalPath = 'C:\Temp', 
    $RootSite = 'https://publicsite.com', 
    $FileExtension = '.gz' 
)

#Define the session cookie used by the site and automate acceptance.  $session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession 
$cookie =  New-Object System.Net.Cookie
$cookie.Name = "name"
$cookie.Value = "True" 
$cookie.Domain = "www.public.com"
$session.Cookies.Add($cookie);

$FileNameDate = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd  
$DownloadFileName = $DownloadPath + $FileNameDate + $FileExtension 
$DownloadFileName 

TRY{
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $WebSite = Invoke-WebRequest $Url -WebSession $session -UseBasicParsing   #this gets the links we need from the main site. 
    $Table  = $WebSite.Links | Where-Object {$_.href -like "*FetchDocument*"} | fl href #filter the results that we need. 
    #Write-Output $Table 
    $FilterTable=($Table | Select-Object -Unique | sort href -Descending) | Out-String

    $TrimString = $FilterTable.Trim() 
    $FinalString = $RootSite + $TrimString.Trim("href :") 
 
    #Write-Verbose $FinalString | Out-String
    #Start-Process powershell.exe -verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-File C:\some\path\base_server_settings.ps1" -Wait
    Invoke-WebRequest $FinalString -OutFile $DownloadFileName -TimeoutSec 600 
        
    $ExpectedFileName = Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 $DownloadPath.Name | SELECT Name 
    $ExpectedFileName
    Write-Host 'The latest DLA file has been downloaded and saved here:' $DownloadFileName -ForegroundColor Green
}

CATCH{
    [System.Net.WebException],[System.IO.IOException]
    Write "An error occured while downloading the latest file." 
    Write  $_.Exception.Message 
}
```

Expectation is that it downloads a file into the downloads folder and does in fact download the file when using the ISE.

When I try to run this as a command however (PowerShell.exe -file "/path/script.ps1) I get an error stating:

An error occurred while downloading the latest file. Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

> out-lineoutput : The object of type
> "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData" is not
> valid or not in the correct sequence. This is likely caused by a
> user-specified "format-*" command which is conflicting with the
> default formatting. At
> \path\to\file\AutomatedFileDownload.ps1:29
> char:9
>
> - ```
>       $FilterTable=($Table | Select-Object -Unique | sort href -Des ...
>   ```
> - ```
>       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [out-lineoutput], InvalidOperationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConsoleLineOutputOutOfSequencePacket,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand

I found several articles describing using the MTA or STA switch and I have tried to add in -MTA or -STA to the command, but it still gives me the same error in the command.

Comment: could you change the `Catch{...code...}` to just `Catch{Throw $_}` Then post what error you get.

Comment: @ArcSet I removed the code and added the Throw $_ instead. It gave me the same error as above.

Comment: It should give you more information like What line the error was thrown at and so on...

Comment: @ArcSet Apologies, I was running the wrong file (from testing). I added the log info in the original post.

Comment: Try  `$Table  = … | Select-Object href` instead of `$Table  = … | fl href`. Output from cmdlet `Format-List` is not mostly usable if saved to a variable…

Comment: @JosefZ I tried and received error: Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert value "https://www.public.com" Error: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

Comment: Also check you variable `$FilterTable`. The way you are constructing it gives you a multiline string. Basically, you are using things like `fl` (aka Format-List) and `Out-String` to give you a single workable string to create an url from. If you are using `$FilterTable` for the new URI, at least make sure you only take one href string from `$Table`, like this: `$FilterTable= ($Table | Select-Object -Unique | Sort-Object href -Descending)[0]`

Comment: @Theo changing that line gave me a new error: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData] does not contain a
method named 'Trim'.

Comment: Yes, because it is not a string..

Comment: Have you seen the comment by @JosefZ ? Apparently, you still kept the `| fl` to get the `$Table` variable..

Comment: @Theo no I removed the FL when changing the code. Were you expecting me to attempt your fix on top of his? Because thats not what I did. I tried his, it failed, and then tried yours which also failed. I can try your fix with JosefZ's fix also if thats what you are asking... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you are trying to get one link from the website, but pipe your commande to things like `Format-List` and `Out-String`, rendering the result to either nothing at all or as a single multiline string.. In both cases, this won't get you what you are after.

Not knowing the actual values of the linksof course, I suggest you try this:

```
Param( 
    $Url           = 'https://randomwebsite.com',
    $DownloadPath  = "C:\Downloads",
    $LocalPath     = 'C:\Temp',
    $RootSite      = 'https://publicsite.com',
    $FileExtension = '.gz'
)

# test if the download path exists and if not, create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $DownloadPath -PathType Container)){
    $null = New-Item -Path $DownloadPath -ItemType Directory
}

#Define the session cookie used by the site and automate acceptance.  
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession 
$cookie =  New-Object System.Net.Cookie
$cookie.Name = "name"
$cookie.Value = "True" 
$cookie.Domain = "www.public.com"
$session.Cookies.Add($cookie);

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

try {
    $WebSite = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -WebSession $session -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop  #this gets the links we need from the main site. 
    # get the file link
    $lastLink = ($WebSite.Links | Where-Object {$_.href -like "*FetchDocument*"} | Sort-Object href -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).href
    # create the file URL
    $fileUrl = "$RootSite/$lastLink"
    # create the full path and filename for the downloaded file
    $DownloadFileName = Join-Path -Path $DownloadPath -ChildPath ('{0:yyyyMMdd}{1}' -f (Get-Date), $FileExtension)

    Write-Verbose "Downloading $fileUrl as '$DownloadFileName'"
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileUrl -OutFile $DownloadFileName -TimeoutSec 600 -ErrorAction Stop

    # test if the file is downloaded
    if (Test-Path -Path $DownloadFileName -PathType Leaf) {
        Write-Host "The latest DLA file has been downloaded and saved here: $DownloadFileName" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "File '$DownloadFileName' has NOT been downloaded"
    }
}
catch [System.Net.WebException],[System.IO.IOException]{
    Write-Host "An error occured while downloading the latest file.`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
catch {
   Write-Host "An unknown error occured while downloading the latest file.`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't realize what you meant in the comments. Thank you for the assistance! We figured it was with the string but wasn't sure the right way to go about it. Appreciate the help!